# Помогите составить FULL JOIN по 3 табицам

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица id content

```
id   |content |
-----|--------|
1    |content1|
2    |content2|
3    |content3|
4    |content4|
5    |content5|
6    |content6|
7    |content7|
```

Есть табличка соотношения Id автора id контента

```
Author_Id |TxtContent_id |
----------|--------------|
100       |1             |
101       |2             |
102       |3             |
103       |4             |
106       |5             |
106       |6             |
106       |7             |
```

Ну и конечно же табличка с авторами

```
Id   |Name         
-----|-------------
100  |Автор 1
101  |Автор 2
102  |Автор 3
103  |Автор 4    
104  |Автор 5
105  |Автор 6
106  |Автор 7
```

Суть вопроса, как мне соединить данные из этих таблиц в один ответ? 
Зависимость между таблицами видна не вооруженным глазом, хочу получить что то вроде

```
id|content|Author_Id|Name
```

Я знаю что нужно ковырять FULL JOIN в MySQL но не могу написать запрос для 3х таблиц. ( просто не хватает опыта в этом деле) подскажите кто знает как сделать такой запрос?

Comment: ну вот есть пример запросов http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/JOIN.html  или https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp что именно ты в них не понимаешь?

Comment: А зачем вам FULL, обычного JOIN (который INNER) более чем достаточно.

Comment: Вот я тоже об этом подумал

Comment: А зачем вы приняли ответ с FULL ? 1. он не может работать в MySQL. 2. Два FULL в запросе могут привести к очень неожиданным результатам и дать вам как контенты без авторов, так а авторов без контента.

Comment: Вот вам пример для MS SQL http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9c08e/1 запроса из принятого вами ответа http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9c08e/1  не правда ли, результат совершенно неожиданный ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так.
Только название таблиц измените на Ваши.

```
select c.id, c.content, a.Author_Id,a.Name
from id_content c 
join id_autor ai on c.id=ai.TxtContent_id
join autor a on ai.Author_Id=a.id
```

Comment: Тоже хороший ответ! :) Спасибо!

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT t2.Author_Id as Author_Id, t2.TxtContent_id as TxtContent_id, t1.content as content, t3.Name as Name 
FROM table2 as t2 
FULL JOIN table1 as t1  ON t2.TxtContent_id = t1.id 
FULL JOIN table3 as t3  ON t2.Author_Id = t3.Id
```

Comment: В MySQL нет FULL JOIN. да и ни к чему он тут

Comment: Как нет? [Вот есть](http://labdes.ru/prostye-primery-join)

Comment: А какое отношение приведенная ссылка имеет к MySQL ? Это описание стандарта SQL. Во многих БД он есть, а конкретно в MySQL его нет. http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/JOIN.html  и вот пример http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ee64b61/4  И главное, _ЗАЧЕМ_ в данном случае FULL ? он используется когда вы хотите показать и из левой и из правой таблицы все записи, вне зависимости он наличия парных по условию ON. Если FULL бы отработал, он бы показал всех авторов, даже для которых нет контента, так же контент без авторов

Comment: Вот как ваш запрос работает на данных автора (от себя добавил одного автора и один контент, которые никак друг с другом не связаны) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9c08e/1  (В MS SQL разумеется, потому что в MySQL это невозможно)

Comment: Читайте комментарии к вопросу пожалуйста, я отказался от FULL JOIN в пользу JOIN ( INNER ) Несколько покурив документацию, понял что даже по логике в моем случае FULL JOIN будет не верным решением

Comment: Ответ отметил другой - я в работе просто, упаролся не туда тыкнул